# What is Christmas Tree Mode in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, syntax-highlighting

Reading `python-mode` mailing lists, I've seen something I haven't heard of in a [posting](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-mode/2010-June/000833.html):

> [...] I can't get all syntax highlighting to work, most particular variable highlighting.  **I have christmas tree mode on**.

Because googling didn't help, I wonder if anyone knows what this mode is and/or does? Is it a tongue-in-cheek definition of `font-lock-maximum-decoration`?

Comment: To the person who flagged "offtopic": do you know any better SE site for this question? AFAIK, Emacs questions have always been allowed on SO, but maybe that changed...

Comment: @rassie: `superuser.com` or `programmers.stackexchange.com` Though the former should be better. Voting to close now.

Comment: @sukhbir: how does a question get moved instead of closing? UPD: Never mind, supposed to be done automatically.

Comment: @rassie: This has been voted as 'off topic' and as soon as there are five votes (two more to go as of now), it will be automatically moved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a way to say you've got everything turned on, all the bells and whistles, or in the case of this analogy, all of the blinking lights and flashy ornaments/ornamentation.  I would probably equate it to cperl's hairy mode, which encompasses behavior as well as visual, but I don't know that that's what the OP was referring to.